# Redactor(WYSIWYG editor) automatically converts Chinese to string in english

Tags: javascript, redactor, redactor.js

I'm using redactor now for a website in Chinese. However, when you type Chinese in the editor like (哈哈哈 - which is "hahaha") - it is automatically converted to "ha ha ha" after saving.

It only happens on my phone (safari in iOS9 but not desktop - chrome). The code is very long, I tried to go through it but couldn't find anything.

It seems like certain Chinese characters got sanitized and messed up. Is there anything particular that I should be looking for?

Comment: Maybe it's your phone setting, do you have an android device to test it with?

Comment: @OlaviSau Sorry but I don't. Why is it related to my phone setting tho? I was still typing in Chinese?

Comment: My line of thought was that perhaps the IOS was converting it.

Comment: @OlaviSau I'm not sure that's the case. it works ok everywhere except for redactor.